# jQuery mobile fixed toolbar workaround for BlackBerry?

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

I'm building a webworks application using jquery mobile.

I want to use the jQuery mobile [fixed toolbar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) but it doesn't seem to be supported in BB7.

Does anyone know of a work around to get a similar toolbar behaviour in BB7?

*EDIT:*

This is the application with fixed header + footer in Android, works on all models I've tested.

[image]

This is how it works on the 9860 on BB 7.1. I can confirm the same problem happens on the following devices BB7.1(9860, 9810, 9320), BB6(9700). Those are all I've tested so far.

[image]

Though the attribute does work on BB7.1(9930) & BB7(9930) as @JasonDScott points out. I've also found it to work on BB7(9360-ATT).

Comment: Which BB7 smartphone are you using?

Comment: Have a handful of simulators but usually 9810 on BB 7.1

Comment: I am running it on 9930 on 7.1 and it looks fine. What is not working with it?

Comment: Hadn't tried 9930 but it seems to work on 9930 across OSs. Have updated my question to reflect what phones it seems to work on and which it doesn't.

Comment: I will look into this issue further for you...

Comment: We just tested 9810 on 7.1.0.556 and it seems fine on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html. Do you have a sample page other than the docs where you see this problem? Can you try to get your hands on a real device (not a simulator), we have noticed some inconsistency between the two.

Comment: @JasonDScott thats good to know. I've tried it on 2 real devices they both worked fine.

Comment: Great! So you are all good now?

Comment: any one knows the solution to this problem ?. iam facing this problem.....

Comment: @Signare - The solution was that this is only a problem on the simulators and you should test with real devices :)

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
$(document).bind("pagecreate", function()
{
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: true });
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: true });
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('show');
});
```